# Variable not available in lexical scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following code:

```
function addToPlaylist ({params}) {
  debugger
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getPlaylistItems().then((items) => {
      if (!items.content) { items.content = [] }
      debugger
      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

Nevermind what it does, it's just a work in progress and it doesn't really work yet, hence why I'm putting debugger calls in there.

My question: why is `params` available at the first breakpoint, but not at the second? I get an 'Uncaught ReferenceError: params is not defined'.

I tried doing `params = params` at the beginning because I thought that was a trick which would work, but it doesn't. I tried `const _params = params` as well, and it wasn't available inside the `then(items) =>` scope either.

What's the deal? I thought Javascript had lexical scoping.

This is happening from a "background script" in a Chrome Extension.

[image: chrome_debugger_1]

[image: chrome_debugger_2]

Comment: Looks like the old _"promise constructor anti-pattern"_ since `getPlaylistItems()` appears to return a promise already

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with `params` though. It should definitely be available. Since you aren't actually using `params` anywhere though, what is telling you it's not there?

Comment: @Phil I do appreciate you pointing that out, but keep in mind this method is only half written. I understand the anti-pattern you're referring to.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I log `params` in the callback it works fine. It would be more helpful if you had code that actually reproduced the problem.

Comment: @maxpleaner I don't see a `params` anywhere in that code, aside from the parameter to `addToPlaylist`. How are you seeing that it's not available? Through the debugger?

Comment: In Firefox, I do get an error for `params` when within the `Promise` ~ _"Error: variable `params' has been optimized out"_ so this is just debugger optimisation I guess

Comment: I don't think that it holds on to the closure since you don't have any reference to params in the callback. It probably just gets GC'd.

Comment: Can you create a simplified version of the code that we can plop into a JS environment and test it?

Comment: Thank you all. Simply writing `params = params` in the inner scope fixed it.